# How to get environment variables in Emacs Elpy Python shell using Pipenv?

Tags: python, emacs, pipenv, elpy

I am using Elpy on Emacs and using pipenv.  When I start an Elpy Python shell or send the current buffer to the shell, I cannot get the environment variables that I set in the terminal.    But I would very much like to be able to send my code and env vars over to the Elpy shell, how can I do that?

The virtual environment is works fine because all my packages are there; also, if I use the pipenv-shell, I can access my env vars.

I checked on `os.environ` and it shows that I'm using the correct virtual environment, and everything else looks just about right there, just none of the variables I set myself.  Is there a way to set the environment variables from Elpy?  I looked at the documentation, but I am still unclear on this.  I would rather use the OS environment variables than "project variables" or anything like that because I need to be able to edit and run the code outside of Emacs as well.

Edit:  OK, I realized that I can use M-x setenv to set the environment variable, which does what I need, but I would still like to know how to get Elpy to recognize already set environment variables.